# A fragment does not show its corresponding layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Any idea why the layout of a ccrosponding `fragment` is not showing. The problem is that, i have two `fragments` "sub" and "pub" and each of them has its own layout. First I designed the layout of the `fragment` "sub" and in "sub"'s class that extends `fragment` I inflated the `view` f the "sub" activity thelayout of "sub". At run time, i find that the `actionTab` "sub" has no `view` and the `view` i designed for it, is displayed on the `fragment` "pub".

please le me know where that error comes from?

**Update"Added Code**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messagin_activity_layout);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    List<Fragment> mFragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    mFragList.add(new Pub_Frag());
    mFragList.add(new Sub_Frag());
```

**Code_"sub_Frag"**

```
public class Sub_Frag extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_frag_layout, container, false);
    EditText et_topic = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_topic); 
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: how you load fragment in activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the order in which you add your framents to the `ArrayList` ,"if you are using it", matters.
make sure that you add your `fragments` t the `arraylist` in the same order you assign hem to `actiontab`